# Can't access my webpage hosted on my public IP

Tags: node.js, server, ip, port, portforwarding

I have made a server using node.js and express.js. Here is the [repo](https://github.com/Wolvborg/wolborg-server). This server is running fine on Heroku. Here is the [link](http://wolborg-server.herokuapp.com). Also, I have forwarded my port like this https://nimb.ws/hCO6ED. But when I access my public IP with port 80, I can't see my webpages. Can someone tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you allowed the port on your firewall/anti-virus/anything you use? Also, are you trying to connect your home ip address from another PC? If so, make sure your ISP didn't put you behind a NAT.

Comment: What public IP did you use? Do you own it?

Comment: @NickLeBlanc not sure about the firewall on anti-virus things, but I am using two laptops both on the same wifi network.

Comment: @shaochuancs do I have to own one?

Comment: @AbhishekSaini Acessing on LAN is different from WEB. Is your node code listening on your LAN IP? server.listen('ip', 'port') or some variation of that.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc I am listening to only port shown in the Image i.e 80. I also have shared my code in the link. https://github.com/Wolvborg/wolborg-server

Comment: @AbhishekSaini Can you try the following: app.listen(YOURPORT, 'YOURIP');